# Including WebLinks Metatype in Package.xml Includes Fields on deploy

Tags: salesforcedx-cli

I am setting up a deployment package and this includes some weblinks I created using the CLI (Deployed using source path). I am trying to target specifically the weblinks and not the fields or anything else underneath an object. Whenever I deploy WebLinks I get many more deployment objects than specified and I noticed it was trying to deploy fields with it, possibly more (i.e RecordTypes, ListViews, etc). Why can I not target just the web links? Is there a better way to do this, that is create a set of items you want to deploy using the CLI?

```
<types>
    <members>Contact.*SomeName1*</members>
    <members>Contact.*SomeName2*</members>
    <members>Contact.*SomeName3*</members>
    <name>WebLink</name>
</types>
```

Answer (score 0):

The manifest option currently deploys an entire object, presumably because it's basically a wrapper for the mdapi. Use the source-path option instead.

```
sfdx force:source:deploy -p force-app/main/default/objects/Contact/webLinks/
```

Comment: If I have several source paths I need to deploy how would I do that in a single source deploy command? Or under this method is that not possible?

Comment: @ZachHutchins Appears to be impossible. That said, you should consider the fact it's possible to organize in to folders/packages. In fact, you might even want to look at Unlocked Packages, which are a lot handier than deploying individual components every time.